# 英語が残っている: 重複アカウントについて問い合わせる時のポップアップ

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

URL: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact

> If you have two accounts that you would like to join together, please
>   provide links to both profiles. We will reach out to confirm your
>   ownership of each account, then complete your merge.
>
> To send a merge request, you must be signed into one of the two
>   accounts - it doesn't matter which one. Can't remember how to log in?
>   Visit our password recovery page.

[image: dup account]

Answer (score 1):

**重複アカウントを統合するには**

アカウントを統合したい場合、両方のプロフィールへのリンクをお知らせください。双方のアカウントの所有者があなたであることを確認できたら、アカウントをまとめる処理を実行します。

統合リクエストを送る際は、どちらかのアカウントにログインしている必要があります（どちらのアカウントでもかまいません）。ログイン方法が分からない場合は、パスワードを忘れた場合の対処方法のページをお読みください。

Answer (score 0):

適当翻訳：

> 二つのアカウントを統合したい場合、両方のプロフィールへのリンクを知らせてください。両アカウントのオーナーを確認した上、統合を実施します。
>
> 上記を要求するため、どっちかのアカウントでログインした状態してください（どっちのアカウントでもいいです）。ログイン方法忘れてたら、このページを参考してください。

Comment: 私の案も別回答で追加しました。